# How to set delta in SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, gesture, swiperefreshlayout

I get little bug in my app.

This is my app structure:
[image]

When I start scroll for move to the next page in `ViewPager` `SwipeToRefreshLayout` catch my swipe and I can't to change page.

How to set delta for `SwipeRefreshLayout`?

Comment: could you please share your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by extending `SwipeRefreshLayout` and disallowing intercepting horizontal scroll like following. This is a modified code I found somewhere on stackoverflow.

```
public class PullToRefresh extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    private final int mTouchSlop;
    private float mTouchDownX;

    public PullToRefresh(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mTouchDownX = event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (Math.abs(event.getX() - mTouchDownX) > mTouchSlop) {
                    return false;
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```